# C++: Warning inconsistent dll linkage

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have an issue with Visual studio (in C++)

I got a warning and I don't know why because I never call 2 time the same variable.

`function: inconsistent dll linkage`

warning list: (in french)
[image: warning list - visual studio c++]

I read on microsoft: [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4273](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28C4273%29&rd=true) but I don't really know if it's my problem because the example is not like mine.

I read also [About inconsistent dll linkage (StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592523/about-inconsistent-dll-linkage) and it tell me that because I use MFC in dll but I didn't check the header MFC.
[image: not MFC header]

it's my "PayRespectdll.h"

```
#pragma once

#ifdef PAYRESPECTDLL_EXPORTS
#define PAYRESPECTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define PAYRESPECTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

namespace PayRespectDLL
{
    class PayRespect
    {
    private:
        static struct std::tm when;
    public:
        static PAYRESPECTDLL_API bool is_setup();
        static PAYRESPECTDLL_API void setup(std::string date);
        static PAYRESPECTDLL_API bool is_possible();
    }
}
```

PayRespectDLL.cpp:

```
// PayRespectDLL.cpp :
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PayRespectDLL.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

namespace PayRespectdll
{
    bool PayRespect::is_setup()
    {
        return false;//already_setup;
    }

    // setup attempt String: hh:mm:ss.
    void PayRespect::setup(string date)
    {
        return;
    }

    bool PayRespect::is_possible()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: You will get this warning when the compiler parsed the declaration and saw __declspec(dllimport).  But then also saw the definition of the function.  That cannot be correct of course, it can't be both imported from another DLL *and* implemented by your code.  Most obvious reason this happened is that you forgot to define or mis-spelled PAYRESPECTDLL_EXPORTS

Comment: When I call my dll from another apps.. I just need to add ".h"... not define something? I follow a tutorial for creating the dll and I think it never saw that I need to define something in my solution. Can you provide me a tutorial to define it properly?

Comment: Right-click your DLL project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor definitions setting.  Add PAYRESPECTDLL_EXPORTS.  Repeat for all other configurations.  This is supposed to be discoverable, spend another hour looking around. Press F1 when you don't understand something.