# Why do I get 4 inconsistent DLL linkage warnings?

Tags: c++

I'm dealing with someone else's code. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273?view=vs-2019), I see that the header may be all that is need to explain why I get 4

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4273   'DTAIAEC_<Init/Run/Shutdown/Push>': inconsistent dll linkage
```

Two definitions in a file differ in their use of dllimport. _WIN32 is "always true". I guess that `__declspec` conflicts with `extern "C"`
My question is how to solve it with:

```
#pragma once


#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef DTAI_AEC_EXPORTS
#define DTAI_AEC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DTAI_AEC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define DTAI_AEC_API
#endif

#include <vector>

#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct {
}DTAIAEC_Multi_SoundBuffer;

typedef struct {
}DTAIAEC_Output_SoundBuffer;

#pragma pack(pop)

typedef int(*DTAIAEC_SoundBuffer_Output_CB_t) (DTAIAEC_Output_SoundBuffer*);

extern "C" DTAI_AEC_API int DTAIAEC_Init(DTAIAEC_SoundBuffer_Output_CB_t SoundBuffer_Res_Callback, int internalChannels);

extern "C" DTAI_AEC_API int DTAIAEC_Run(void);

extern "C" DTAI_AEC_API int DTAIAEC_Shutdown(void);

extern "C" DTAI_AEC_API int DTAIAEC_Push(DTAIAEC_Multi_SoundBuffer*);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About inconsistent dll linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592523/about-inconsistent-dll-linkage)

Comment: I understand that in `extern...` DTAI_AEC_API is replaced by __declspec(dllimport) in programs that need to import my module and exported by my module itself. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/128199 is a dead link.  DTAI_AEC_EXPORTS is  defined in the project files (Preprocessor Definitions). once

Comment: Do you get the warning on the lines in the header, or in a source file somewhere else (with the various `DTAIAEC` functions declared as `__declspec(dllexport)`)? Are you using a precompiled header?

Comment: But indeed, an importing project references this header. So, can / should / how to fix this? (It won't be imported by any other projects than the one that imports it now.

Comment: I get the warning in the .cpp files that implement the header. Not in the importing module (i.e. main).

Comment: `int DTAIAEC_Run(void){}`